# (!) Plugin svelte: No custom element 'tag' option was specified

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I try to compile a Svelte component into a web component.

1. added the option `<svelte:options tag="date-picker" immutable={true}/>`
2. added `customElement: true` in rollup to `plugins: [ svelte()`
3. run `npm run build`

But I keep having the message:

> (!) Plugin svelte: No custom element 'tag' option was specified. To
>   automatically register a custom element, specify a name with a hyphen
>   in it, e.g. . To hide this warning,
>   use

What am I doing wrong?

My `index.js` file:

```
export { default as default } from './DatePicker.svelte';
```

`DatePicker.svelte` file:

```
<svelte:options tag="date-picker" immutable={true}/>

<script>
  /* code */
```

The rollup file:

```
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import pkg from './package.json';

const name = pkg.name
    .replace(/^(@\S+\/)?(svelte-)?(\S+)/, '$3')
    .replace(/^\w/, m => m.toUpperCase())
    .replace(/-\w/g, m => m[1].toUpperCase());

export default {
    input: 'src/index.js',
    output: [
        { file: pkg.module, 'format': 'es' },
        { file: pkg.main, 'format': 'umd', name }
    ],
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            customElement: true
        }),
        resolve()
    ]
};
```

It seems that if your project consists of a single component, the message doesn't appear. See issue here:

https://github.com/sil-vio/svelte-web-components/issues/2

Answer (score 1):

Importantly, the correct place to add the compilerOptions is in *svelte.config.js* and not in *vite.config.js*.
I have a book that has it wrong and I could not get rid of the error until I realised it was the wrong file named in the book. Here is my svelte config, and upon saving this file the linter stopped complaining.

```
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

export default {
  // Consult https://svelte.dev/docs#compile-time-svelte-preprocess
  // for more information about preprocessors
  preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
  compilerOptions: {
    customElement: true,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `tag: null` additionally to your rollup-plugins-svelte section.

```
...
         { file: pkg.main, 'format': 'umd', name }
        ],
        plugins: [
            svelte({
                customElement: true,
                tag: null
            }),
            resolve()
        ]
    };
```

If you are looking for a working example:
https://github.com/ivosdc/svelte-generic-crud-table/blob/master/rollup.config.js

Comment: This is a legit solution to set `null` by default . Minor nit, for newer versions of svelte set this option in `svelte.config.js` roughly like this:
`const config = { compilerOptions: { tag: null } }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the `customElement` option one step deeper, like this

```
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      compilerOptions: {
        customElement: true,
```

You can see this in the rollup-plugin-svelte docs: https://github.com/sveltejs/rollup-plugin-svelte#usage